# trying to bind enter click to onkeyup event of a field

Tags: javascript, html

So in normal situation where jquery i allowed and i can bind the field onkeyup i would use:

```
$('#something').keyup(function(e) {
    var enterKey = 13;
    if (e.which == enterKey){
        somefunction();
     }
 });
```

however i cannot use this and will have to use something like:

```
<input id="something" onkeyup="onkeyup_colfield_check(this)" type="text">
```

```js
 function onkeyup_colfield_check(e){
    var enterKey = 13;
        if (e.which == enterKey){
            somefunction();
        }
}
```

However this doesn't work like the above.

how can i achieve the same result like the first example but with something like that?

Comment: Why can't you use jQuery ?

Comment: cannot use in what i am doing right now. jquery is not yet loaded at this stage

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to pass in `event` as an argument, not `this`.

```
<input id="something" onkeyup="onkeyup_colfield_check(event)" type="text">
```

Also, to be fully compatible with all major browsers, you may want to use the following for detecting te key code of the key pressed.

```
var charCode = (typeof e.which === "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
```

Comment: You don't need to check which/keyCode  - jQuery fixes this for you, just use one or the other.

Comment: yea that worked didnt knew that there are browsers that might case problem thanks for that

Comment: @NetaMeta - Glad to help. Please select this as the accepted answer =D

Comment: Nope no jquery not for this one

Comment: Like I said he/she certainly isn't